# (invalidPackageJSON, @testing-library/react)

Tags: package.json

that I need to add package.json mui in my react project and then error with @testing-library/react": "^13.4.0

```
"name": "react-test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.14.16",
    "@mui/material": "^5.14.16",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
```